# Overlay of div over button with background colour

Tags: html, css, button, overlay

I have a button in my html page with background colour of white and then a span with text hello. I have wrapped my button and span in a div with id overlay. To that overlay id I am giving a background colour of brown with z-index of 10. But the brown colour is not coming over the button. What can be the problem?

```css
button {
  background: white;
  color: blanchedalmond;
}

#overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <button>Next</button>
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it required that the **overlay** must be on the parent? This can be done if it is okay to create another child element that will act as an overlay

Comment: `z-index` has no effect on background colors. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Set button `background` brown as well

```
#overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  background: brown;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay::before {
    content: '';
    background: brown;
    width: 51px;
    height: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't change the button css. Only overlay css can be changed.

Comment: @RaghavGupta i updated my code now check

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` works only with positioned elements. There are static positions in your code. The button appear after the overlay container.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that In DOM structure the elements are stacked on top of their parents by default. So the child's background will overshadow the parent background. To create effects like overlay; you need to use positions structures (absolute) or z-index for stacking it to top.

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
  background: white;
  color: blanchedalmond;
}
#overlay{
  position:relative;
}
#overlay:after {
  z-index: 10;
  position:absolute;
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <button>Next</button>
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need this thing or you want to show overlay on hover?

Comment: Yes this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for this. This will make the button transparent and make the button non clickable, only using CSS

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <button>Next</button>
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have given background: white to button that's why it is showing white in background just replace the (background:white;) to (background:transparent;) and change the color property of button to relative to color;

Comment: No I can't change the button background. Only overlay css can be changed. Purpose of overlay is to cover the elements inside it.